# What about non-flight-based craft?

Tags: discussion, scope

I used to work for an entity that built [UUVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_underwater_vehicle) (or underwater drones), which were really neat. They used them to test sonar systems.

That said, they're likely very different in how they work and the components to achieve that (flight vs swim) but I'd also imagine that a lot of the communication systems would be similar. So... if someone were to ask a question about them here would that be in scope?

Considering the name of the site, it's possible it won't ever happen... but when I saw this proposal, this was the question I had.

Answer (score 7):

Just posting the other perspective to allow for democratic voting.

#### Yes, we should allow questions about underwater drones.

Here are the pro's I've thought of:

- They both deal with remotely controlled unmanned vehicles
- Some of the components on homemade drones and UUVs are similar / same (particularly communcations components)
- It allows the site to cover a similar subject which will be unlikely to be welcome on any other SE site
- It takes a similar skillsets to answer questions about both subjects

---

Actually the more I think about it the more I think they should be allowed :)

Answer (score 2):

I think these should be out of scope, these use [very different systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_underwater_vehicle#Vehicle_designs) in my opinion from the navigation methods and the senors. I don't think there is a community there to be able to expand our scope to this, so I do believe this would be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If the site title were solely about drones, I could see it. But we throw model airplanes in, which really limits it to aircraft. I just don't see aquatic drones working.