# What topics should be on-topic for asking questions on Drones and Model Aircraft SE?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

The current scope for asking questions on this site, as defined [here](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the help center, is quite lacking in information. As it stands, it contains only the basics of asking questions on SE sites. We would like to add more specific information to help future questions better fit the scope of this site.

If you have any suggestions or ideas for what should be added to "*[What topics can I ask about here?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*", please leave them in an answer below. (one suggestion per answer). This includes adding what is off-topic as well.

**Note:** If it is undecided if a subject is off-topic or not, please [make a new Meta post](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 4):

Per [this meta post](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/what-about-non-flight-based-craft/46#46) it bears mentioning that non-flight based drones such as underwater drones are on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

### Software issues

Any issues regarding the software for a Drone / Model Aircraft are on-topic. The question should include details of the software, including: the name of the software, what is the problem and what the user has tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

### Hardware issues

Hardware issues with a Drone / Model Aircraft are on-topic The question should include: what the hardware problems is, the name/type of Drone, an image of the issue where possible and what the user has tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [Meta Post](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/whats-our-stance-on-recommendation-questions-now), it seems that the general consensus is that recommendation questions are on-topic (with some requirements)

Comment: Can you expand on some of these requirements here please? e.g. enough details, not too broad etc. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To stay on topic one should ask questions promoting the future of drone and remote controlled flight in any medium.  This should be related to safety, building, history, or experiential sharing.  Promoting knowledge that improved aviation and remote controlled flight data in all areas of the future.

Off topic should be things that destroy the hobby that had promoted so many developments in aerospace through history.